# How do I fix MovieBox from crashing as soon as it opens in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, movie

I have MovieBox installed and it will work for a few days but after a while, whenever I try to open it, it will immediately crash. I searched on the internet and tried the following:

- Turn on airplane mode, kill all apps, then open it
- Set the date back 1-2 years

There was another suggestion to delete a file in `/var/` with iFile, but my phone is not jail broken so I don't think that would work, nor would I be able to install iFile by Carsten Heinelt.

I've always had to delete the app and re-install it, but I don't want to delete any movies that I've already downloaded or favorited.

iPhone 5, iOS 9

Comment: I've given up on MovieBox and started using CinemaBox (playboxhd.net).